# Problem with placing of views inside a linear layout

Tags: java, android-linearlayout

So i have tried to place the imageview to the left with gravity but this doesn't work also i have tried to put it to the left with weight but that also did not work.

I want to place the profile picture all the way to the left and the username right next to the profile picture.

But with adding gravity="START" to the profile picture the problem was not solved

Here is my code.

```
private void retrieveImages() {
        final long MAX_SIZE = 5 * 1014 * 1024;

        // Create the horizontal LinearLayout to hold the profile picture and username
        LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // Create the vertical LinearLayout to hold the post image and description
        LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Define parent container
        GridLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.GlPosts);

        //Adding everything to layouts
        imagesRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                    String name = item.getName();

                    //Getting profile picture and adding to
                    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            String email = snapshot.child(name).child("Email").getValue(String.class);
                            String storageEmail = email.replace(";", ".");
                            StorageReference profileRef = storage.getReference().child("profiles").child(storageEmail);
                            profileRef.getBytes(MAX_SIZE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                                    ImageView profilePicture = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                    profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams profileParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
                                    profileParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
                                    profilePicture.setLayoutParams(profileParams);

                                    // Adding the profile picture to the same horizontal LinearLayout
                                    linearLayout1.addView(profilePicture);
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to load image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    //Adding post image to linear layout
                    item.getBytes(MAX_SIZE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                            ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            linearLayout2.addView(image);

                            //Adding post description to linear layout
                            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    String description = snapshot.child(name).child("Description").getValue(String.class);

                                    TextView Description = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    Description.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    Description.setText(description);
                                    Description.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                                    linearLayout2.addView(Description);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to load image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    //Adding username to linear layout
                    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            String email = snapshot.child(name).child("Email").getValue(String.class);
                            String username = snapshot.child("profiles").child(email).child("Username").getValue(String.class);

                            TextView usernameDisplay = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                            usernameDisplay.setText(username);
                            usernameDisplay.setTextSize(20);
                            usernameDisplay.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            usernameDisplay.setGravity(Gravity.START);

                            // Adding the username to the same horizontal LinearLayout
                            linearLayout1.addView(usernameDisplay);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    // Add the two LinearLayouts to the parent GridLayout
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                    layoutParams1.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
                    layoutParams1.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
                    parentLayout.addView(linearLayout1, layoutParams1);

                    GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                    layoutParams2.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(1);
                    layoutParams2.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
                    parentLayout.addView(linearLayout2, layoutParams2);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to list items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

and XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/logo"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="55dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.109"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IvCalender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.809"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/calendar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IvNotes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.91"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/notes" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IvAddPost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/GlPosts"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.939"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IvHome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/IvAddPost"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.302"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/GlPosts"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IvProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.69"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/IvAddPost"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/GlPosts"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.939"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/user" />

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/GlPosts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TvTitle"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.173" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).